# Calculate mean over specific time period at night (pandas, python)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, temperature

I want to calculate the nightly (21:00-05:00) mean temperature of a dataset consisting of datetime-measurements with temperature values and station names for a specific station (station_a) for a special time period of three days in May.

What I tried so far:

```
heat_days = data.loc[(data['time'] > '202205180000') & (data['time'] < '202205202359')]

#overall mean temperature
mean_heat_station = heat_days["temperature"].loc[(heat_days['name'] == 'station_a')].mean()

#nights
heat_nights = heat_days.between_time('21:00', '5:00')
mean_night_station_a = heat_nights["temperature"].loc[nights['name'] == 'station_a'].mean()
```

I throws me a TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex and I do not know why. The error occurs with the heat_nights = heat_days.between_time('21:00', '5:00').
I read in the data like this:

```
data = pd.read_csv(
    fp,
    sep = ";",
    parse_dates =["time"],
    encoding = "unicode_escape"
)
```

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data to work with?

Comment: If you get errors, it's also important to know which line exactly throws the error - if you call `data['time']` and that errors out, did you make sure your dataframe has a column named 'time' ?

Comment: I updated it @FObersteiner  and yes the column is named like this

Comment: ok, not totally obvious from [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) but your dataframe's index must be a DatetimeIndex to use `between_time`. So use something like `data = data.set_index('time')` before.

Comment: I tried that before - when I do this, it throws me the a key_error for time at: heat_days = data.loc[(data['time'] > '202205180000') & (data['time'] < '202205202359')]

Comment: did you try a more "standard" format like `'2022-05-18 00:00'`?